# How to enable dropdown menu of code coverage runners in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, code-coverage

Could anyone advise on how to enable the dropdown menu of code coverage runners in Android Studio (v3.2.1)?

The dropdown menu is located at Menu bar -> Run -> Edit Configurations -> Android JUnit -> Code Coverage tab -> Choose coverage runner.

Here is a link to the screenshot of the Code Coverage page.

[image]

I am aware of the following warning in the screenshot:

> Code coverage is supported for jre 5.0 or higher

but I already have JRE 10 installed on my computer.